# Custom Windows XP Installation Disk

Tags: windows, windows-xp, installation

I'd like to build some custom windows xp installation disk that would install windows with some custom settings. This is pretty easy so far. Some apps like Nlite would do the trick.

But what I'm wondering is: is it possible to install some applications automagically?

I'd like to install apps such as Autocad 2010, Office 2007, etc. So every time I have to setup a new workstation, I wouldn't have to install everything every time.

Every workstation does not have the same hardware so I can't make a ghost image of a already installed drive and just restore it on some new hard disks...

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Symantec Backup Exec System Recovery can do this on different hardware using the "master" image on a system.  Also handy if there is a system crash.  We have used it to go from a three year old PC to a new laptop with little difficulty.

There is a 60 day trial at[BackupExec](http://www.backupexec.com)  The Desktop Edition will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to SYSPREP the drive and use on cross hardware, providing the processors are the same family.  I had the most success recreating the image after I got a new machine, until I had a good variety of drivers on my image.  I think the most I had setup was 10 different PC models off of one image.